# 'advance' keyword in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

```
let word = "sample string"

let firstLetter = Character(word.substringToIndex(advance(word.startIndex,1)).uppercaseString)
```

I got the above example from a tutorial. Can anyone know what they mean by "advance" and what is difference between "substringToIndex" and "substringWithRange".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `advance` syntax is from Swift 1, it's different now.

**Swift 2**

```
let firstLetter = Character(word.substringToIndex(word.startIndex.advancedBy(1)).uppercaseString)
```

The `advancedBy` method moves the current index along the String.

With `substringToIndex` you slice a part of the String, beginning at the start of the String and ending at the index defined by `advancedBy`.

Here you advance by 1 in the String, so it means that `substringToIndex` will get the first character from the String.

**Swift 3**

The syntax has changed again, we now use `substring` and an `index` with an offset:

```
let firstLetter = Character(word.substring(to: word.index(word.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)).uppercased())
```

Answer (score 1):

**substringToIndex**

> Returns a new string containing the characters of the receiver up to,
>   but not including, the one at a given index.
>
> **Return Value** A new string containing the characters of the receiver up to, but not including, the one at anIndex. If anIndex is
>   equal to the length of the string, returns a copy of the receiver.

**substringWithRange**

> Returns a string object containing the characters of the receiver that
>   lie within a given range.
>
> **Return Value** A string object containing the characters of the receiver that lie within aRange.
>
> **Special Considerations** This method detects all invalid ranges (including those with negative lengths). For applications linked
>   against OS X v10.6 and later, this error causes an exception; for
>   applications linked against earlier releases, this error causes a
>   warning, which is displayed just once per application execution.

For more info detail, you can get in the [Apple NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringWithRange:)

Answer (score 1):

Your tutorial is outdated. `advance` was deprecated in Swift 2. Strings in Swift cannot be randomly accessed, i.e. there's no `word[0]` to get the first letter of the string. Instead, you need an `Index` object to specify the position of the character. You create that index by starting with another index, usually the `startIndex` or `endIndex` of the string, then advance it to the character you want:

```
let word   = "sample string"
let index0 = word.startIndex                // the first letter, an 's'
let index6 = word.startIndex.advancedBy(6)  // the seventh letter, the whitespace
```

`substringToIndex` takes all characters from the left of string, stopping *before* the index you specified. These two are equivalent:

```
print("'\(word.substringToIndex(index6))'")
print("'\(word[index0..<index6])'")
```

Both print `'sample'`